# django SimpleListFilter

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
# models.py

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    licence_key=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    exp_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.customer_name
```

I want to have a custom list filter in admin site that shows customer that their `exp_date` has been passed. It should have two parameters `valid` and `invalid`  for example and compare `exp_date` with today's date and show the result. I've read it can be done by simplelistfilter but I couldn't figure how.

Thank you and sorry for my english

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the below code. It will provide you to filter with the valid/invalid customers list.

```
class ExpiryDateFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

    title = _('Title name')

    parameter_name = 'exp_date'

   def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
       """
           List of values to allow admin to select
       """
       return (
          ('valid', _('All Valid')),
          ('invalid', _('All Invalid')),
       )

  def queryset(self, request, queryset):
     """
         Return the filtered queryset
     """

    if self.value() == 'valid':
        return queryset.filter(exp_date__gt=datatime.datatime.now())
    elif self.value() == 'invalid':
        return queryset.filter(exp_date__lt=datatime.datatime.now())
    else:
        return queryset
```

In the admin class add a list filter like the following.

```
class youModelAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):

     list_filter = [ExpiryDateFilter]
     list_display = ['CustomerValidity']
```

and then register the model admin with you Django model.

```
admin.site.register(ModelClassName, youModelAdminClass)
```

Hope this will help.